# How to show a tooltip on button click using Angular1

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angularjs-ng-click

I have designed a tooltip using only html and css.I cannot use bootstarp.Below is my code for tooltip.

```
<div class="box">
  <h3>Tooltip</h3>
</div>




    h3 { 
        text-align:center; 
        line-height:33px;
    }

    div.box {
        height:100px;
        width:200px;
        background-color:#eee;
        border:1px solid #aaa;
        position:relative;              
        top:50px;
        left:50px;
        border-radius:7px;
    }

    .box:before {
        position:absolute;              
        right:-20px; 
        top:5px;
        content:'';                     
        height:0;
        width:0;
        border:10px solid transparent;
        z-index:1;                      
    }

    .box:after{
        position:absolute;          
        right:-17px;    
        top:25px;
        content:'';                         
        height:0;
        width:0;
        border-top: 8px solid transparent;
        border-left: 8px solid #aaa;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;        
        border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
        z-index:1;                  
    }
```

The tooltip is working.But i want this tooltip to come **on button click that is on ng-click** as i am using **Angular1**.
Can anyone please help me how to do this.I am very new to Angular1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first add a ng-show to your tooltip

```
<div class="box" ng-show="displayTooltip">
  <h3>Tooltip</h3>
</div>
```

and add ng-click to your button to make displayTooltip true

```
ng-click="displayTooltip = true"
```

if you want to make tooltip invisible on button click use

```
ng-click="displayTooltip = !displayTooltip"
```

or if you want to make it invisible on mouseleavevent use

```
ng-mouseleave="displayTooltip = false"
```

Comment: Thanks @NTP. Its working.But one thing , I want to make tooltip invisible when i click outside of page(Not on button click).
How to acheive that.Can you please tell me.

Comment: you can also  add the ng-click function to your div

Comment: When i am adding ng-click to div ,then onclick of div only its getting invisible.
I want to make it invisible when i click outside of div. @NTP

Comment: adding ng-click to the outer div should do the trick but it is difficult to guess without seeing the code, if you update your question I am sure we can figure something out.

Comment: Actually i want it like this.I have one button.And on that button click tooltip should show exactly left to that button.And i am not able to adjust this.
for now my code is like below.
<div class="box" ng-show="displayTooltip">
  <h3>Tooltip</h3>
</div>
 <button ng-click="displayTooltip = true" >OK</button>
@NTP