# Keeping primeng tooltip visible after clicking on the associated div

Tags: angular, tooltip, primeng

I have a custom tooltip component that uses primeng to display the configured tooltip. I have a use case where the tooltip needs to be visible after clicking on the div where it is available. This does not happen, and the tooltip ends up being invisible right after I click the div. I have tried the following:

- focus on the div with the tooltip when `(click)` and set tooltip event to focus - this did not work
- Assign a template reference to the div with the tooltip and then try to activate the tooltip on `(click)` - [How to show primeng tooltip only on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72109664/how-to-show-primeng-tooltip-only-on-click)
- Also tried the Angular equivalent of this - [How to show a tooltip on button click using Angular1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726530/how-to-show-a-tooltip-on-button-click-using-angular1), [What is the equivalent of ngShow and ngHide in Angular 2+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular-2)

Is there any other way to keep the pTooltip open after the asspciated div is clicked?